# Kotlin extensions for GraphQL

Tags: kotlin, graphql, kotlin-extension, netflix-dgs, kotlin-dsl

We are stuck using an old version of Netflix DGS for GraphQL. It lets us write a schema and generates Java classes. A query looks something like this:

```
FooProjectionRoot()
  .bar()
  .baz()
  .parent()
  .yolo()
```

where the GraphQL structure was something like

```
type Bar {
  baz: String
}

type Foo {
  bar: Bar
  yolo: Int
}
```

Now we would like to use the Kotlin DSL to write queries like this instead:

```
FooProjectionRoot {
  bar {
    baz
  }
  yolo
}
```

We wrote an extension function and got close, but still have this helper function `g` that should disappear. Now queries look like this:

```
fun <T : BaseProjectionNode> T.g(initializer: T.() -> Unit): T {
    return this.apply(initializer)
}

FooProjectionRoot().g {
  bar().g {
    baz()
  }
  yolo()
}
```

The generated code for any type looks something like this:

```
class Foo : BaseProjectionNode {
  fun bar() {
    val bar = Bar()
    // add bar to output
    return bar
  }

  fun yolo() {
    // add yolo to output
    return this
  }
}
```

So every attribute has a method that either returns `this` or the next lower level. I would love to add a new method for each existing method that takes the init block as a parameter, calls the original method and then applies the init block. Is something like this possible?

Comment: This might be what you're looking for, or at least similar: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/type-safe-builders.html

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I'm doing at the moment. What I don't understand is if from my call to `f(init)` i can make a call to the original `f()` method.